# Querying a grails tree object

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a Section domain that looks like this. I build the navigation from it and order stories under sections or sub sections eg: news > crime > the great train robbery

```
class Section {
    String name;
    String path
    Section parent;
    Boolean active = true;
    int level = 0;
    Boolean isRoot = false;
    static hasMany = [children:Section]
    static mappedBy = [children:'parent']
    static mapping = {
        parent :'all-delete-orphan' 
        parent lazy:true
    }
}
```

The Story domain that looks like this

```
    class Story 
    {
        String title;
        String story;
        List link;
        List substory;
        List picture;
        Section publishUnder
        boolean parent = false;
        boolean approved = false;

        Date dateCreated;
        Date lastUpdated;

        static belongsTo = [author:Author]

        static hasMany=
        [
           link:String,
           substory:Story,
           picture:Picture
        ]
   }
```

We have 7 root sections:

Home, News, Sport, Travel, Tech, Culture and Comment and with the exception of Home they all have child sections

eg: News will have a level below it containing  UK, Europe, USA then USA could have another level of child sections for containing Politics and Crime Sections. Stories as mentioned above are stored under Sections. So a story "Obama Impeached" would have as its published under value
**News > USA > Politics**.

I have to write a query that will get n number of stories which are stored under one of the children of the top level sections. So if I pass in the 'News' Section as parameter (there might not be any stories stored directly under "News" but there may be under **News > Uk> Crime**) I want to return stories that are stored under any child section of "News"

How do I do this with gorm? Should I use HQL? I'm still a noob to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple solution like this:

First, to speed things up, I would have a Sections Tree in a memory cache. When you start up the application, you can create this Tree and store it in an applicatin context:
In grails-app/conf/BootStrap.grrovy , you can do this inside init closure

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    servletContext.sectionsTree = something
}
```

To create this "something", you can traverse the sections children recursively and construct a list or map that contains all children´s id of each section... something like:

```
rootSections = [[section:root1, childrenIds:[23,45,67,89,5,43,45,6,7,87], children:[section:child1, childrenIds:[23,45,67]]], [section:root2, childrenIds:[32,43,54,65,76], children:[]]]
```

Where childrenIds contains all IDs from the sections children, and children of children.

So now, you can execute a simple HQL query to get the Section´s Stories:

```
Story.executeQuery("select s from Story s where s.publishUnder.id in (?)", [childrenIds]);
```

Thats just one solution....se what you think about it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks felipenasc. I'll try that as soon as I have time and get back to you. I hadn't thought of it like that.

Comment: Hi Sorry for teh delay I've been away.

Comment: Hi Felipe I couldn't get the code to work as I wanted. However I solved it by adding a rootNode property to the Section domain then using `Story.where( publishUnder.rootNode = sectionRoot )` where sectionRoot is equal to 'News' or 'Sport' ect. Thanks for taking the time out to answer.